# Run ng e2e with --element-explorer not working

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing, angular-e2e

I'm trying to figure out how I can debug my end to end tests. I'm usage protractor in an angular project and using the `protractor-cucumber-framework` custom framework.

```
Given('[...]', async () => {
  await page.goToMeetupsListPage();
  const profile: Profile = getMichel();
  await page.setProfile(JSON.stringify(profile));
  await page.refreshPage();
});
```

I'm setting a break point in this kind of function.

Then I run the command `ng e2e --element-explorer` which is supposed to look for break points.

Then I get this error on launch:

```
/Users/.../node_modules/protractor/built/debugger.js:212
                    doneDeferred.fulfill(true);
                                 ^
TypeError: doneDeferred.fulfill is not a function
    at Socket.tester.once (/Users/b.../node_modules/protractor/built/debugger.js:212:34)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:441:20)
    at TCP._handle.close (net.js:611:12)
```

I have no idea what's happening. I tried removing every `async/await` keywords but still the same message. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently `--element-explorer` param seems not to work for debugging e2e tests. Instead you need to run manually protractor with `--inspect-brk`

```
node --inspect-brk ./node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor ./e2e/protractor.conf.js
```

Then just follow the [official guide](https://www.protractortest.org/#/debugging#disabled-control-flow).

Comment: Yup! For future reference, element-explorer is going away (very very soon) because the control flow is going away. The control flow is selenium-webdriver's promise manager. A quick review of your above code, it looks like you are using async / await. In order to use async / await you would need to turn off the control flow promise manager so element-explorer will not work for you.